# How to render a material-table using a JSON that comes from a API response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I'm new on ReactJS and this is my first page that I created, but I'm having some problems with set variables.

What I need is fill the variable **table.data** with the values that comes from `const response = await api.get('/users')` and render the table with this values when page loads.

I have the following code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Fade } from "@material-ui/core";
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import api from '../../services/api.js';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        width: '70%',
        margin: 'auto',
        marginTop: 20,
        boxShadow: '0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)'
    }
}));

function User(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

    let table = {
        data: [
            { name: "Patrick Mahomes", sector: "Quaterback", email: "patrick@nfl.com", tel: "1234" },
            { name: "Tom Brady", sector: "Quaterback", email: "tom@nfl.com", tel: "5678" },
            { name: "Julio Jones", sector: "Wide Receiver", email: "julio@nfl.com", tel: "9876" }
        ]
    }

    let config = {
        columns: [
            { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
            { title: 'Sector', field: 'sector' },
            { title: 'E-mail', field: 'email'},
            { title: 'Tel', field: 'tel'}
        ],
        actions: [
            { icon: 'create', tooltip: 'Edit', onClick: (rowData) => alert('Edit')},
            { icon: 'lock', tooltip: 'Block', onClick: (rowData) => alert('Block')},
            { icon: 'delete', tooltip: 'Delete', onClick: (rowData) => alert('Delete')},
            { icon: 'visibility', tooltip: 'Access', onClick: (rowData) => alert('Access')},
            { icon: "add_box", tooltip: "Add", position: "toolbar", onClick: () => { alert('Add') } }
        ],
        options: {
            headerStyle: { color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)' },
            actionsColumnIndex: -1,
            exportButton: true,
            paging: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            pageSizeOptions: [],
            paginationType: 'normal'
        },
        localization: {
            body: { 
                emptyDataSourceMessage: 'No data' 
            },
            toolbar: { 
                searchTooltip: 'Search',
                searchPlaceholder: 'Search',
                exportTitle: 'Export'
            },
            pagination: {  
                labelRowsSelect: 'Lines',
                labelDisplayedRows: '{from} to {to} for {count} itens',
                firstTooltip: 'First',
                previousTooltip: 'Previous',
                nextTooltip: 'Next',
                lastTooltip: 'Last'
            },
            header: {
                actions: 'Actions'
            }
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setChecked(prev => !prev);

        async function loadUsers() {
            const response = await api.get('/users');
            table.data = response.data;
        }

        loadUsers();
    }, [])


    return (
        <>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />

            <Fade in={checked} style={{ transitionDelay: checked ? '300ms' : '0ms' }}>
                <div className={classes.root}>
                    <MaterialTable editable={config.editable} options={config.options} localization={config.localization} title="Usuários" columns={config.columns} data={table.data} actions={config.actions}></MaterialTable>
                </div>
            </Fade>
        </>
    );
}

export default User;
```

The previous example will show 3 users that I fixed on variable **table.data** with 4 columns (name, sector, email, tel).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since `table.data` is not a state variable, it is regenerated as it was declared originally every time the component renders, meaning that by the time it arrives as a prop to your component it will always be the same value (when you change the value of `table.data` in `useEffect` it is too late). You need to change `table.data` to a state variable, and then in your `useEffect` hook you can update the value of `table.data` to the value of `response.data`. This will cause the component to be re-rendered but with the updated value.

Here's an example of how you might do that:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Fade } from "@material-ui/core";
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import api from '../../services/api.js';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        width: '70%',
        margin: 'auto',
        marginTop: 20,
        boxShadow: '0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)'
    }
}));

function User(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);


    let config = {
        columns: [
            { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
            { title: 'Sector', field: 'sector' },
            { title: 'E-mail', field: 'email'},
            { title: 'Tel', field: 'tel'}
        ],
        actions: [
            { icon: 'create', tooltip: 'Edit', onClick: (rowData) => alert('Edit')},
            { icon: 'lock', tooltip: 'Block', onClick: (rowData) => alert('Block')},
            { icon: 'delete', tooltip: 'Delete', onClick: (rowData) => alert('Delete')},
            { icon: 'visibility', tooltip: 'Access', onClick: (rowData) => alert('Access')},
            { icon: "add_box", tooltip: "Add", position: "toolbar", onClick: () => { alert('Add') } }
        ],
        options: {
            headerStyle: { color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)' },
            actionsColumnIndex: -1,
            exportButton: true,
            paging: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            pageSizeOptions: [],
            paginationType: 'normal'
        },
        localization: {
            body: { 
                emptyDataSourceMessage: 'No data' 
            },
            toolbar: { 
                searchTooltip: 'Search',
                searchPlaceholder: 'Search',
                exportTitle: 'Export'
            },
            pagination: {  
                labelRowsSelect: 'Lines',
                labelDisplayedRows: '{from} to {to} for {count} itens',
                firstTooltip: 'First',
                previousTooltip: 'Previous',
                nextTooltip: 'Next',
                lastTooltip: 'Last'
            },
            header: {
                actions: 'Actions'
            }
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setChecked(prev => !prev);

        async function loadUsers() {
            const response = await api.get('/users');
            setTableData(response.data);
        }

        loadUsers();
    }, [])


    return (
        <>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />

            <Fade in={checked} style={{ transitionDelay: checked ? '300ms' : '0ms' }}>
                <div className={classes.root}>
                    <MaterialTable editable={config.editable} options={config.options} localization={config.localization} title="Usuários" columns={config.columns} data={tableData} actions={config.actions}></MaterialTable>
                </div>
            </Fade>
        </>
    );
}

export default User;
```

Answer (score 0):

In a functional component, each render is really a new function call. So any variables you declare inside the component and destroyed and re-created. This means that `table` is set back to your initial value each render. Even if your `useEffect` is setting it correctly after the first render, it will just be reset on the next.

This is what state is for: to keep track of variables between renders. Replace your `let table`, with a new state hook.

```js
const [table, setTable] = useState({
  data: [
    { name: "Patrick Mahomes", sector: "Quaterback", email: "patrick@nfl.com", tel: "1234" },
    { name: "Tom Brady", sector: "Quaterback", email: "tom@nfl.com", tel: "5678" },
    { name: "Julio Jones", sector: "Wide Receiver", email: "julio@nfl.com", tel: "9876" }
  ]
});
```

Then use it like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setChecked(prev => !prev);

  async function loadUsers() {
    const response = await api.get('/users');
     setTable(prev => ({...prev, data: response.data});
  }

  loadUsers();
}, [])
```